# Project Server: the server farm account should not be used for other services error

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, error, project-server, managed-account

I just recently installed Project Server on my SharePoint Server and used my farm account to install. Now I'm working on resolving errors that get thrown with using the farm account to install.

3 Errors:

1. Microsoft Project Server Events Service executes events triggered by
   changes to entities on the Project Server.(Windows Service)
2. Microsoft Project Server Calculation Service manages the lifecycle
   and the communication of the processes that handle modifications to
   projects.(Windows Service)
3. Microsoft Project Server Queuing Service executes project related
   jobs asynchronously. Example queue jobs: Save project, publish
   project, submit timesheet.(Windows Service)

Do any of the following services need to access to the farm account or can i move them to other managed accounts using central admin?

The reason I ask is because user profile sync service needs to be used by the farm account, I'm not aware if there are other services in a similar situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Farm Account, which is used for the SharePoint 2010/2013 Timer service and the Central Administration site, is highly privileged and should not be used for other services on any computers in the server farm.

You need to Change the Server farm account used for other services to low privileged account. This error may vary as per the services running in your environment.

http://badalratra.wordpress.com/2013/07/13/the-server-farm-account-should-not-be-used-for-other-services/

User Profile Services is special case because required to provision the FIM services on backend. As far as I know, no other services required under this account.